# Notepad plus plus Find and Replace question

Tags: replace, find, notepad++

I want to insert a line break before and after a specific string in Notepad ++

to the glory

```
<hr />
<strong>Collect:</strong>
```

I want to achieve this

to the glory

```
<hr />

<strong>Collect:</strong>
```

can I do this in Notepad++ ?

Comment: yes you can. So you want to insert a linebreak before and after "to the glory" everywhere in the file?

Comment: Do you want linebreaks arround `<hr />` or arround `<strong>Collect:</strong>`?

Answer (score 0):

You could find the horizontal rule and replace with the full match `$0` and append a newline in front and after.

**Find what:**

```
^<hr />$
```

**Replace with:**

```
\n$0\n
```

[Pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/Iv55HN/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex capturing group like this:

[image]

and then use find and replace.